# Error while adding a user in WSO2ESB

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

When I try to add a user in WSO2ESB I am getting this kind of message below"Error while loading roles. Error is: Error while fetching roles from JDBC user store according to filter: % & max item limit: -1"
What could be the problem? I am using Informix database. JDBC 3.7

Comment: what is the database you are using?

Answer (score 0):

This error could occur due to the version incapability in connector jar. Try updating the connector jar to a newer version.